# Статистика игрального кубика на 10000 раз Python

Tags: python, теория-вероятностей

```
print((f"\ndice roll\n").upper())
import random
def diceroll():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    return roll
sum_roll_1 = 0
sum_roll_2 = 0
sum_roll_3 = 0
sum_roll_4 = 0
sum_roll_5 = 0 
sum_roll_6 = 0
diceroll()
for i in range(10000):
    if diceroll() == 1:
        sum_roll_1 += 1
    elif diceroll() == 2:
        sum_roll_2 += 1
    elif diceroll() == 3:
        sum_roll_3 += 1
    elif diceroll() == 4:
        sum_roll_4 += 1
    elif diceroll()==5:
        sum_roll_5 += 1
    elif diceroll()==6:
        sum_roll_6 += 1
print((f'статистика на 10000:\n').upper())
print(f"1 выпала {sum_roll_1} раз\n2 выпала {sum_roll_2} раз\n3 выпала {sum_roll_3} раз\n4 выпала {sum_roll_4} раз\n5 выпала {sum_roll_5} раз\n6 выпала {sum_roll_6} раз\n")
print(sum_roll_1 + sum_roll_2 + sum_roll_3 + sum_roll_4 + sum_roll_5 + sum_roll_6)
```

Помогите разобраться почему при проверке суммы не выходит 10_000

Comment: Потому что «кидать кубик» надо один раз перед if-ами. А так вы в каждом if-е проверяете новый бросок

Comment: И ещё используйте словарь для аккумуляции результатов. Ну или список. Зачем плодить отдельные переменные, если можно сгруппировать в один объект.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что с вероятностью *(5/6)<sup>6</sup>* не один из шести счётчиков не увеличивается. Это вероятность примерно равна одной трети (совпадение). Треть попыток теряется.

Разберём по случаям:

1. вероятность получить единицу равна *1/6*. Тут всё честно.
2. вероятность получить двойку равна *5/6 * 1/6*. Первый множитель - *P("не единица")*, второй *P("двойка")*. Они перемножаются так как это два вызова `diceroll()`, которые предполагаются независимыми.
3. вероятность получить тройку равна *5/6 * 5/6 * 1/6*. Первый множитель - *P("не единица")*, второй - *P("не двойка")*, третий - *P("тройка")*. Они перемножаются так как это три вызова `diceroll()`, которые предполагаются независимыми.
4. вероятность получить четвёрку равна *(5/6)<sup>3</sup> * 1/6*.
5. вероятность получить пятёрку равна *(5/6)<sup>4</sup> * 1/6*.
6. вероятность получить шестёрку равна *(5/6)<sup>5</sup> * 1/6*.
7. Вероятность ничего не получить равна *(5/6)<sup>6</sup>*.

Таблица:

> ```
> исход  формула           значение
> 1      1/6               0.167
> 2      5/6 * 1/6         0.139
> 3      (5/6)^2 * 1/6     0.116
> 4      (5/6)^3 * 1/6     0.096
> 5      (5/6)^4 * 1/6     0.080
> 6      (5/6)^5 * 1/6     0.067
> -      (5/6)^6           0.335
>
> сумма  1                 1.000
> ```

Проверка на практике:

> ```
> DICE ROLL
>
> СТАТИСТИКА НА 10000:
>
> 1 выпала 1694 раз
> 2 выпала 1374 раз
> 3 выпала 1145 раз
> 4 выпала 962 раз
> 5 выпала 804 раз
> 6 выпала 638 раз
>
> 6617
> ```

Предсказанные вероятности довольно хорошо совпали с реальными результатами.

Проблема в том что нельзя при сборе статистики вызывать `diceroll` несколько раз. Один вызов, одно увеличение счётчика:

```
...
for i in range(10000):
    roll = diceroll()
    if roll == 1:
        sum_roll_1 += 1
    elif roll == 2:
        sum_roll_2 += 1
    elif roll == 3:
        sum_roll_3 += 1
    elif roll == 4:
        sum_roll_4 += 1
    elif roll == 5:
        sum_roll_5 += 1
    elif roll == 6:
        sum_roll_6 += 1
...
```

Статистика сразу выправляется:

> ```
> DICE ROLL
>
> СТАТИСТИКА НА 10000:
>
> 1 выпала 1675 раз
> 2 выпала 1669 раз
> 3 выпала 1696 раз
> 4 выпала 1669 раз
> 5 выпала 1652 раз
> 6 выпала 1639 раз
>
> 10000
> ```

Если немного причесать вашу программу получится:

```
import random


def diceroll():
    return random.randint(1,6)


print(('\ndice roll\n').upper())
sums = [0] * 7
for i in range(10000):
    sums[diceroll()] += 1

print(('статистика на 10000:\n').upper())
for i in range(1, len(sums)):
    print(f'{i} выпала {sums[i]} раз')
print()
print(sum(sums))
```